Is there a way to use ORACLE procedure as a source of a phisical table in ORACLE OBIEE?
It seems that Oracle Bi Administration Tool lets you use 'Stored Proc' Table type as a source of a phisical table. It lets you use Database Specific SQL - say Oracle 12 - for initialization string. All that makes me believe it is doable to use Oracle stored proc here.

Does anyone of you know what should be the right usage of this option?
I tried with DMBS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT like here:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BISAMPLE.RESULT_P AUTHID DEFINER AS
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 FOR
SELECT NAME
     , INCOME_LVL
  FROM BISAMPLE.SAMP_CUSTOMERS_D;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT (c1);
END;
/

Then in RPD I created phisical table (2 columns Name, and Income), for source I used type of 'Stored Proc' and called BISAMPLE.RESULT_P with exec command. It does not seem to work.

No idea, I don't use that tool. However, at bottom left corner of the screen I see For Help, press F1. Did you try it? What does it say? Also, is that described in documentation? Did you read it?

Depends really on what the stored proc is supposed to return. If its result set is a table then you can use the same approach as outlined here: http://obiee101.blogspot.com/2011/01/obiee-using-mssql-stored-procedure-as.html

Thank you Chris, but here I was asking specifically for Oracle procedure since I was a bit puzzled with one of their notes in the doc. section. On one hand the tool lets you select Stored Proc of Oracle type, but on the other hand they state "it might not return result sets." so "You cannot initiate stored procedures from within OBI". Taking all that I was wondering if anyone ever used Oracle procedure from within the module depicted in my question.

What "module"? And it doesn't matter what the source tech is. If your stored proc returns data in the format of a table you can use it.
